# How to calculate the derivative of $\frac{1}{2} x \cdot Ax + b \cdot x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm stuck on the following exercise:

> Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $b \in R^n$. We consider the following >function:
>
> $$f\colon  x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \frac{1}{2} x \cdot Ax + b \cdot x$$
>
> Calculate the first and second derivative of $f$.

My idea would be to use the rule for the Derivative of the dot product (as seen [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Dot_Product_of_Vector-Valued_Functions)):

Let

$$\mathbf r\colon x \mapsto \left\langle{r_1 \left({x}\right), r_2 \left({x}\right), \dots, r_n \left({x}\right)}\right\rangle$$

$$\mathbf q\colon x \mapsto \left\langle{q_1 \left({x}\right), q_2 \left({x}\right), \dots, q_n \left({x}\right)}\right\rangle$$

It holds:

$$\dfrac d {d x} \left({\mathbf r \left({x}\right) \cdot \mathbf q \left({x}\right)}\right) = \mathbf r' \left({x}\right) \cdot \mathbf q \left({x}\right) + \mathbf r \left({x}\right) \cdot \mathbf q' \left({x}\right)$$

But the presence of the matrix $A$ in $f$ confuses me. Could you help me?

Comment: Why $r$ is in bold while $x$ isn't? Both are vectors. Or you mean the derivative with respect to some component $x_i$?

Comment: $r$ and $q$ are both vector valued functions.

Comment: I'll make an edit

Comment: Would it be less confusing if you wrote ${\mathbf q}(x)=Ax=\sum_{k=1}^nA_kx_k$ where $A_k$ are the columns of $A$?

Comment: I was worried about the notation $d/dx$, but I guess you mean the gradient. Your function is $$\sum_{i,j} A_{ij }x_i x_j +\sum_i  b_ix_i.$$ I'm sure you will know how to continue.